# Listar propiedades con un @CustomAnnotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, annotation

Al levantar el proyecto , la idea es agarrar todas las Variables que contengan la anotacion @AppProperty.

Probando no logro poder obtener el listado , y siempre me llega un listado vacio. Estoy utilizando la funcion getBeansWithAnnotation() de ApplicationContext. Mi teoria es que al momento de que se ejecuta la busqueda , todavia no se hayan cargado, pero no puedo confirmar que sea eso

Este es el comienzo del proyecto , donde utilizo el @EventListener para que se ejecute luego de levantar el proyecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahi se llama al ApplicationPropertyService en donde intento poder obtener el listado de todas las propiedades que contengan la anotacion @AppProperty

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estas son las dos propiedades que deseo que me aparezcan.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código debe ir como texto por favor. ;)